# Is it right to use different feature scaling techniques to different features?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, feature-scaling

I read this post about feature scaling:
[all-about-feature-scaling](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-about-feature-scaling-bcc0ad75cb35)

The two main feature scaling techniques are:

1. `min-max scaler` - which responds well for features with distributions which are **not Gaussian**.
2. `Standard scaler` - which responds well for features with **Gaussian** distributions.

I read other posts and examples, and it seems that we always use **one** scaling method (`min-max` or `standard`) **for all the features**.

I haven't seen example or paper that suggests:

```
1. go over all the features, and for each feature:
1.1 check feature distribution
1.2 if the feature distribution is Gaussian:
1.2.1 use Standard scaler for this feature
1.3 otherwise:
1.3.1 use min-max scaler for this feature
```

1. Why we are not mixing the scaling methods ?
2. What is wrong or disadvantages with my proposal ?

Comment: Apart from being rather off-topic here (not a *programming* question), I think you will get much more reliable answers in [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), where I suggest you migrate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then, your features will have different scales, which is a problem because the features with the larger scale will dominate the rest (e.g., in [KNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092448/accuracy-difference-on-normalization-in-knn)). The features with min-max normalization will be rescaled into a [0,1] range, while the ones with standardization will be transformed into a negative to positive range (e.g., [-2,+2] or even wider in the event of small standard deviations).

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler

dfTest = pd.DataFrame({'A':[14,90,80,90,70],
                       'B':[10,107,110,114,113]})

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
dfTest['A'] = scaler.fit_transform(dfTest[['A']])

scaler = StandardScaler()
dfTest['B'] = scaler.fit_transform(dfTest[['B']])

ax = dfTest.plot.scatter('A', 'B')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

[image]